# x-editable prompt before updating the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I am working with x-editable (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html), is there way, to show a confirm (warning) prompt before updating the values of the control? If user opt cancel, the value should be reset to old value, in my case it is type=checklist

-George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my self, we can use validate method to show the confirm box, hope this is useful for future references,

-George