# Add confirm prompt before saving x-editiable

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

How do I add a confirm prompt before saving x-editiable (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)?  If the response to the confirm prompt is negative, the x-editable dialog should close and the value should not be updated.

I came up with this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8vjmqtq/4/), but the first solution is a little verbose and the second solution (based on [x-editable prompt before updating the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304308/x-editable-prompt-before-updating-the-value)) doesn't work.

```
Test 1<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="name1"></a>
<br>
Test 2<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="name2"></a>

$('#name1').on('shown', function(e, editable) {
    var button=$('input.myClass').parent().next().find('button.editable-submit');
    console.log(button,e,editable,this);
    button.click(function(){
        if(!confirm("Are you sure you wish to proceed?")){
            editable.hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

$('#name1').editable({inputclass:'myClass'});

$('#name2').editable({
    validate: function (x) {
        console.log(x,this);
        if(!confirm("Are you sure you wish to proceed?")){
            //Doesn't work
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [x-editable documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) says you need to return a string when the input is invalid. I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8vjmqtq/7/) with a working sample.

```
$('#name2').editable({
    validate: function (x) {
        console.log(x,this);
        if(!confirm("Are you sure you wish to proceed?")){
            // Hide the editable
            $('#name2').editable('toggle');
            return "invalid";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I wish the outcome to be the same as my first solution.  Your solution is definitely more concise, but displays the error text and doesn't close the dialog.  Can we get a hold of the dialog object in the `validate` callback so it could be hidden?

Comment: @user1032531 I have updated the sample with a toggle call. The fiddle is also updated.

Comment: I had just come up with almost the same thing, but used `$(this).editable('hide');`.  The returning of a string as you suggested was the key!  Thanks!